# how to open taskpane when I click on button?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins, customtaskpane

manifest.xml

```
  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="SmartFieldButton">
                                    <Label resid="SmartFieldButton.Label" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="SmartFieldButton.Label" />
                                        <Description resid="SmartFieldButton.Tooltip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="smart_field_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="smart_field_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="smart_field_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <TaskpaneId>CIBtn2</TaskpaneId>
                                        <SourceLocation resid="SmartField.Url" />
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
```

[image]

when click this open button open below task pane in angular

[image]

open smartfield task when click open button

Answer (score 1):

Your XML markup for a custom ribbon command which opens a task pane looks good, for example, you may find the following sample markup in the [Create add-in commands with the XML manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands) article:

```
<!-- Define a control that shows a task pane. -->
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button2Id1">
  <Label resid="residLabel2" />
  <Tooltip resid="residToolTip" />
  <Supertip>
    <Title resid="residLabel" />
    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
  </Supertip>
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon2_32x32" />
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon2_32x32" />
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon2_32x32" />
  </Icon>
  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
  </Action>
</Control>
```

If you need to open the task pane programmatically, take a look at the `Office.addin.showAsTaskpane()` method:

```
function yourJSCallback() {
    Office.addin.showAsTaskpane()
    .then(function() {
        // Code that enables task pane UI elements for
        // working with the current quarter.
    });
}
```

Read more about that in the [Show or hide the task pane of your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/show-hide-add-in) article.

Note, to use the `showAsTaskpane()` and `hide()` methods, your add-in must use the [shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtimes#shared-runtime). For more information, see [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime).